# How to validate that a regular expression is valid in Java using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using web forms to let the user specify a regular expression which is later matched in java. I want to check the regular expression provided by the user to see if it is valid. Of course I want to do it on both ends - the java part is easy.

But what would be the best way to check that the regular expression is valid in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Pass it to the `RegExp` constructor in a `try ... catch` block?

Comment: The only problem with using `RegExp` is that JavaScript regex does not allow lookbehind, whereas Java's regex does (and other features in the same boat), so you could fail client side something that would work server-side.

Comment: @Jan, there was an edit made to your post that I don't think is correct, it completely changes the question. Can you please confirm / deny if that edit is accurate?

Comment: Ops, yea, sometimes I am surprised java stuff works in javascript too :)

Comment: @vcsjones: I don't think the edit was correct either, I've rolled it back.

Comment: Thanks for rolling it back, it was incorrect

Comment: Pointy: want to make it answer? It would be just enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) instead of native RegEx?

Answer (score 0):

Client side scripting is good for scalability and performance but when it comes to validation and security you would want to consider using server controls. Because javascript and other client-side scripting languages tend to be bypassed by malicious attackers. Click this [link](http://securitylifer.blogspot.com/2010/08/bypassing-client-side-input-validation.html) to read more about it.

Comment: They know that already! "Of course I want to do it on both ends..."